# Firebase - Querying in flattened data with Two Way Relationship

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a Firebase database with the following structure

```
// Tracking two-way relationships between users and groups     {  
 " users": {  
   "mchen": {  
     "name": "Mary Chen",  
     "groups": {       
        "alpha": true,  
        "charlie": true  
     }  
   },  
   ...  
 },      "groups": {  
   "alpha": {  
     "name": "Alpha Group",  
     "members": {  
       "mchen": true,  
       "donald": true  
     }  
 },   "bravo": {  
   "name": "Bravo Group",  
     "members": {  
       "mickey": true,  
       "donald": true  
     }  
   },  
   ...  
 }
}
```

How do I write a query to show me all the groups a given set of users have in common. i.e. show me all groups where Mickey and Donald both registered.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with a single query, and multiple equalTo are not supported.

I would restructure your database as such

```
root
L users
L groups
  L groupName
    L ...
L groupMembers
  L groupName
    L userName:true
```

Then query like

> Query is reference.child('groupMembers').orderByChild('Donald').equalTo(true);

Then go through the results

```
List resultList
for all DataSnapshot's as snapshot in dataSnapshot's Children
  if snapshot.child('Mickey') is not null
    add to resultList key of snapshot


// resultList now contains all group keys/names which Donald and Mickey are both appart of.
```

That would be one way to solve your problem, but you would initially be downloading groups which Mickey might not be apart of. this may or may not be what you want (security etc..).

If you wanted to only get groups which they are both appart of without any clientside filtering, you would have to restructure your database to something like this.

```
root
L users ...
L groups ...
L groupPairs
  L groupName
    L DonaldMickey:true
```

Your query would look similar, adding/removing a user from a group would be more elaborate. You would have to make sure that every possible pair is under the groupName. You could reduce the amount of pairs by setting a criteria like for example: Donald before Mickey because D is before M, or something like that.